# jest js: wicg-inert included cannot redefine property inert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to make a simple unit test in a React Modal. If it mounts with no props. Here is the test.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import MyModal from ".";
import "wicg-inert";
import "animate.css";

describe("MyModal component", () => {
  describe("When props is missing", () => {
    it("should be defined", () => {
      expect(() => mount(<MyModal />)).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

The error message:

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: inert
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

  4 | import classnames from "classnames";
  5 | import MyButton, { MyButtonGroup } from "components/MyButton";
> 6 | import "wicg-inert";
  7 | import "animate.css";
  8 |
  9 | import "./MyModal.scss";

  at node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:794:10
  at node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:2:66
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:5:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/MyModal/MyModal.jsx:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/MyModal/index.mjs:1:318)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/MyModal/MyModal.test.js:3:32)
```

In the inert.js file inside the node modules. First line is 792.

```
 var inertManager = new InertManager(document);

 Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'inert', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function get() {
       return this.hasAttribute('inert');
    },
    set: function set(inert) {
       inertManager.setInert(this, inert);
    }
 });
```

Absolutely no idea how to solve it, can't find anywhere an explanation.

Comment: [`wicg-inert`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wicg-inert) is designed to only be run once on a page and it runs as soon as it is imported.  My guess is that it gets imported somewhere in your code so when it gets imported again at the top of your test it causes the error.

Comment: If i remove the line "import "wicg-inert";" rfom .test.js, the test works only in the first time, the second time it runs it fails, so its a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --silent **--no-cache**",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "doc": "jsdoc -R src/README.md src/ -r -d doc/"
  },
```

In `test.js` remove the line:

```
import "wicg-inert";
```